# NSNumberFormatter unable to allow numbers to start with a 0

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsnumberformatter

So I'm attempting to automatically add slashes between 2 digits when a user enters in their birthday, but for some reason when the birthday starts with a 0, the number formatter erases it and messes up the birthday. I've got my code below, could someone help me figure out how to do this? Thanks in advance!

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] ;

[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@"/"];
[formatter setGroupingSize:2];
[formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
[formatter setSecondaryGroupingSize:2];
NSString *num = textField.text ;
if(![num isEqualToString:@""])
{
    num= [num stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""];
   NSString *str = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[num doubleValue]]];
    textField.text=str;
}
```

Comment: I have not tried it but you should try the number formatters method  [setAttributedStringForZero](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/setAttributedStringForZero:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is the following:

- Check the length of the string
- If length mod 2 == 0 then add "/"
- Log your string

I'm **not** saying this is recommended but it might help you a bit!

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj{
    NSString *num = [textField stringValue] ;

    if (num.length%2==0)
    {
        NSString *someText = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/ ", num];
        num = someText;
    }
    textField.stringValue = num;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may help:

```
  NSMutableString *string = @"YOUR TEXTFIELD TEXT";
  NSString *lastString = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(string.length-2, 1)];
  if ([lastString isEqualToString:@"/"]) {
    return;
  }
  if (string.length == 2 || string.length == 5) {
    [string appendString:@"/"];
  }
```